# Regex: matching pattern fails

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to match a pattern with re in python, but I can't seem to get a match no matter how I try.

This is my matching pattern:

```py
def get_report_date(report):
    report_data = {}
    with open(report, 'r') as f:
        report_date = re.findall(f'([Q\d \d\d\d\d\s])', f.read())[0]
        pprint(report_date)
        report_data.update({f"{report_date.replace(' ', '_')}": report})
        return report_data
```

and a piece of the file I'm trying to match:

```
(In millions, except number of shares which are reflected in thousands and per share amounts) 

See accompanying Notes to Condensed Consolidated Financial Statements. 

Apple Inc. | Q2 2018 Form 10-Q | 1 Apple Inc. CONDENSED CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF COMPREHENSIVE INCOME (Unaudited)
```

I'm trying to scrape the `Q2 2018`

But I keep getting empty strings.

Comment: `[Q\d \d\d\d\d\s]` is the same as `[Q\d\s]`

Comment: It still returns empty strings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegExp: `r'(Q\d\s\d+\s)'`

Explanation:

1. `r` prefix for raw string
2. `Q` to match the `Q` of quarter
3. `\d` to match the quarter number afterward
4. `\s` to match space
5. `\d+` to match multiple numbers which are the year
6. `\s` to match space

Example:

```
import re

text = """(In millions, except number of shares which are reflected in thousands and per share amounts)

See accompanying Notes to Condensed Consolidated Financial Statements.

Apple Inc. | Q2 2018 Form 10-Q | 1 Apple Inc. CONDENSED CONSOLIDATED STATEMENTS OF COMPREHENSIVE INCOME (Unaudited)"""


x = re.findall(r'(Q\d\s\d+\s)', text)[0]

# Q2 2018 
print(x)
```

Code Fix:

```
def get_report_date(report):
    report_data = {}
    with open(report, 'r') as f:
        report_date = re.findall(r'(Q\d\s\d+\s)', f.read())[0]
        pprint(report_date)
        report_data.update({f"{report_date.replace(' ', '_')}": report})
        return report_data
```